# svn log shows only a subset of the history of file

Tags: svn

I created a branch from a trunk that contains a file named "x.y" with a large history:

```
svn copy trunk-URL branch-URL -m "New Branch"

svn log -g branch-URL
```

shows me the complete history including the file "x.y". So file "x.y" was added with revision 97123. But

```
svn log -g branch-URL/path/to/x.y
```

shows only a subset of the history of file "x.y" beginning with revision 98783.

File `x.y`was never deleted in history. There's not delete flag "D" if I run

```
svn log -g -v branch-URL | grep x.y

...
M ../x.y
M ../x.y
A ../x.y
```

The file `x.y` were added or modified but not deleted.

What‘s the reason that

```
svn log -g branch-URL
```

shows the complete history including file "x.y" but

```
svn log -g branch-URL/path/to/x.y
```

does not?

Answer (score 0):

I can guess that the file `x.y` was removed and then re-added in r98782 or older, then it was re-added. What changes do you see in r98783? Was the file added again in this revision?

Examine the file's history before r98782 and try running `svn log -g branch-URL/path/to/x.y@98782` (use peg revision @98782 or older).

You can find more details in [SVNBook | Resurrecting Deleted Items](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/branchmerge/basicmerging/#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.resurrect) and [SVNBook | Peg and Operative Revisions](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/advanced/pegrevs/).

Answer (score -1):

To show the complete history after reintegration use

```
--use-merge-history (-g)
```

See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.use_merge_history